# No Title Bar on Emacs 25 + Mac

Tags: init-file, osx, frames

I'm running Emacs 25.1 on macOS Sierra. After opening Emacs using the GUI and maximizing its frame, I execute (`C-x C-e`) the following code:

```
(setq ns-auto-hide-menu-bar t)
(set-frame-position nil 0 -24)
(set-frame-size nil (display-pixel-width) (display-pixel-height) t)
```

This code moves the Emacs frame up so that the title bar is hidden, and then resizes the frame so that it fills the entire screen.

**Problem:** If I add the code above to my `init.el` file and relaunch Emacs, the title bar is not hidden anymore. But if I open my `init.el` and `C-x C-e` the mentioned code, then the title bar goes  away.

**Question:** How can I make the code above work properly inside my `init.el` file?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I' having trouble getting past the first sentence and reconciling it with your code.  Why are you maximizing the frame, and then adjusting the size after you maximize it?  How are you maximizing the frame?  Why not set the frame size and position exactly and forego playing around with maximizing it beforehand?

Comment: What's the difference between what you're trying to do and just making the frame fullscreen with `(toggle-frame-fullscreen)`?

Comment: @lawlist by maximizing the frame I mean expanding the Emacs "window" to occupy the entire screen (`toggle-frame-maximized`). However, that leaves the title bar still visible, and I want to get rid of the title bar.

Comment: @stevoooo that is a possible solution, but it is not what I am looking for. Making Emacs fullscreen on a Mac will move it to a "new Desktop", and add a bunch of animations when alt-tabbing around other applications. I am trying to achieve an effect similar to fullscreen borderless on Windows.

Comment: Ah, OK I see what you mean! Hrm actually that would be quite useful for me too - the animations when switching between desktops drives me nuts...

Comment: It works if you have unchecked Preferences -> Mission Control -> Displays have separate Spaces. I have a rough idea why Emacs behaves differently in this case, I'll try to find time to see if I can fix this in future releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force it, you could use a hook which is called after emacs sets its frame parameters.

Like this:

```
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook (lambda()
                                 (setq ns-auto-hide-menu-bar t)
                                 (set-frame-position nil 0 -24)
                                 (set-frame-size nil (display-pixel-width) (display-pixel-height) t)))
```

*Note*, that the sequence of your code is not working with every operating system (Window Manager) as you expect. But if your code worked with `C-x C-e`, then this should solve your problem.

Also `(toggle-frame-fullscreen)` is doing a similar thing like you want.

If you are interested you might have a look at the [emacs startup summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Adding that hook solved the issue! I didn't want to use `toggle-frame-fullscreen` because it moves the Emacs window to a "new desktop" window, and it adds some unwanted animations when using alt-tab.